# Angular Kendo UI Combobox Clear

Tags: angular, combobox, kendo-ui, selectionchanged

I want to clear the selection of my kendo-combobox.

```
<kendo-combobox #products [data]="productData" [(ngModel)]="selectedProduct" (selectionChange)="handleSelectionChange($event)" [textField]="'DisplayName'" [valueField]="'ID'"></kendo-combobox>
```

As you can see I got a two way binding with ngModel. When I set "selectedProduct" to null the combobox seems to be empty & reseted.

But here is my problem:
When I select the same item as i have selected before setting the selectedProduct to null the combobox does not trigger "selectionchange".

So how can I reset the Kendo Combobox properly the angular way?
And is there maybe a way to trigger the function behind the clear button of the combobox programmatically? This would solve my problem too.

Hope you guys can help me, thanks.

Comment: just make selectedProduct = []  empty array that might help

Comment: Thank you for your input. 
SelectedProduct is actually an object. I have already tried to set it as an empty object and set it undefined. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use two-way binding for your ComboBox. You can set the two-way binded variable to `undefined` in order to clear the selection.

Same behavior as using the clear button on the component: [Kendo ComboBox clearButton](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/ComboBoxComponent/#toc-clearbutton)

```
options: {Title: string, Value: string} = [
    ...
];

selectedOption: {Title: string, Value: string};

<kendo-combobox
    [data]="options"
    textField="Title"
    valueField="Value"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"
</kendo-combobox>

function onClickDelete() {
    this.selectedOption = undefined;
}
```